# PHP Concatenating in multiple quotes

Tags: php, concatenation

I need to put $row['key'] in schedule.php?id= but I'm having trouble with concatenating

```
echo ' {label:"<a style=\'color:black\'target=\'_blank\' href=\'schedule.php?id='".$row['key']."' \'>'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</a>"},';
```

Comment: Why are you building JSON by hand?  Make an array and then use `json_encode`.

Comment: *It looks like you're trying to cobble together JSON by hand. Would you like to learn more about `json_encode` or other sane alternatives?*

Comment: @RocketHazmat The OP is clearly new to the whole thing. Perhaps this is all he knows. Perhaps you should give him some guideline with an example that may help him.

Comment: @itsols: I *did* post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't build JSON by hand, create an array, then `json_encode` it.  This should make it easier to juggle with your quotes.

```
$data = array(
    'label' => '<a style="color:black;" target="_blank" href="schedule.php?id='.$row['key'].'">'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</a>'
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighter makes it easy to see your error. You just got your quotes backwards:

```
id='".$row['key']."' \'>'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</a>"},';
  ^^^^           ^^^^
  HERE           HERE
```

should be

```
echo ' {label:"<a style=\'color:black\'target=\'_blank\' href=\'schedule.php?id="'.$row['key'].'" \'>'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</a>"},';
```

As mentioned in the comments above, this is not the best way to construct JSON. Look into [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to see how it can make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following updated code :

```
echo " {label:'<a style=color:black target=_blank href=schedule.php?id=".$row['key'].">'".$row['fname']."' '".$row['lname']."'</a>'},";
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Your HTML attributes need to be quoted.  Why did you remove those quotes?